# Making form inputs float to the right?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the 2nd input form of each go all the way to the right.

I tried putting float: right, but it messed up the entire form.

Here's what I have right now:

HTML:

```
<form action="pdotest/test.php" method="post">

            <div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <label>First Name:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Province:</label><br/>
                    <select name="Province">
                        <option value="volvo">Alberta</option>
                        <option value="saab">British Columbia</option>
                        <option value="mercedes">Manitoba</option>
                        <option value="audi">New Brunswick</option>
                        <option value="audi">Newfoundland and Labrador  </option>
                        <option value="audi">Northwest Territories</option>
                        <option value="audi">Nova Scotia</option>
                        <option value="audi">Ontario</option>
                        <option value="audi">Prince Edward Island</option>
                        <option value="audi">Quebec</option>
                        <option value="audi">Saskatchewan</option>
                        <option value="audi">Yukon</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <label>Last Name:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Postal Code:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="postalcode" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <label>Address Line 1:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="addressline1" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Phone Number (day):</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <label>Address Line 2:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="addressline2" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Postal Code:</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="postalcode" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text], select {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y13ac506/1/

I don't really want to use margin/padding.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I'll use Flex for this: https://jsfiddle.net/d8a4y37g/

Comment: Basically I just want the 2nd column to be aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different `div`s with `float:left` & `width:50%` style. The two will align side by side.Then put the input as per your requirment

```css
.container{
  width:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <label>First Name:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <label>Province:</label><br>
 <select name="Province">
     <option value="volvo">Alberta</option>
  <option value="saab">British Columbia</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Manitoba</option>
  <option value="audi">New Brunswick</option>
  <option value="audi">Newfoundland and Labrador </option>
  <option value="audi">Northwest Territories</option>
  <option value="audi">Nova Scotia</option>
  <option value="audi">Ontario</option>
  <option value="audi">Prince Edward Island</option>
  <option value="audi">Quebec</option>
  <option value="audi">Saskatchewan</option>
  <option value="audi">Yukon</option>
 </select> 
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <label>Postal Code:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="postalcode"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I don't want to use bootstrap in this.

Comment: then use two different divs as container and set one of them` float:left` with 50% with and drop the input the way you want

Comment: Edited. have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use float:right and then add flowing code in end:

```
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </form>
```

Note: This is easiest not best way according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing the value of width

```
 input[type=text], select {
  width: 250px; 
 }

/* manage it with margin for appropriate spacing around input fields..
```